# apt-get returns strange error

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, kali-linux

I am on kali linux and when I run apt-get update it returns this:

```
W: Unknown flag value:  yes
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

after running `apt-get update` several times it's still the same issue

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25773555/350713

Comment: no one answering me on overflow

Comment: You can ask for the question to be migrated. In any case, you should wait a little while - you only posted on SO 15 hrs ago. Also, this is not an error, it is a warning, and can be ignored. It should not affect anything.

Comment: Have you checked your sources.list?

Comment: Yea everything is fine with the source file

Comment: Confirmed: I got the same error: commenting out Bleeding Edge repo resolved the issue. I will uncomment the repo later to see if its been fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the:

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main
```

I think you should wait for kali.org to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct `sources.list` contents is, at the time of writing,

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Please refer to [the official Kali Linux documentation on this matter](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in this repository:

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main
```

Remove that repository. After kali.org has fixed that bug, you can use Bleeding Edge repositories again.